# Elementary Geometry : Structure of presentation

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, angle

I will have a presentation on elementary geometry, and more precisely on the straight line and the triangle.

The presentation should be in the university, in front of the fellow students.

For this I use the book "Elementary Geometry" by Ilka Agricola, Thomas Friedrich (chapters 1.1 and 1.2).

The following topics are discussed there with regard to the straight line:

- Intercept theorem
- Pappus's hexagon theorem
- Desargues's theorem
- Theorem of Thales

And regarding the triangle:

- Theorem: A triangle is isosceles if and only if two of its inner angles are equal.
- Theorem: A triangle is equilateral if and only if its three interior angles are equal.
- Exterior angle theorem
- Sum of angles in a triangle
- Alternate angle theorem

So would the structure of the presentation mention all of these topics and prove some of them? Or what do you think?

Comment: Start by showing the topics and some examples. Do you have some time after it? If yes, continue with more complex examples. More time? Then show proofs, starting at the simplest. The idea is "more time, then more complexity".

Comment: Ok! At which theorems do you think that we have to give more emphasis and give also the proof? @Ripi2

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, this depends on your presentation and the rules.

However, examples always help in math. Explain it, show the equation, then give an example, preferably visual. Especially for geometry, make things visual. It's way easier to show things than just talk about it.

About your question about more emphasis on specific questions, it really depends on what the rules are. If I were you I would go over theorems that you feel are more special or useful. Prove the important ones, depending on how much time you have.

-FruDe

Comment: For the presentation I have 45 minutes. According to you which of the theorems are more important so that I should mention them?

Comment: So we could give the proof of one theorem about the lines and one theorem about the triangles and for some others we could give examples. But from whoch theorems do ypu suggest to give the proof?

Comment: Again, it really depends on your requirements but choose what you think will be the most interesting and which you are comfortable with. Personally I think Desargues's or Pappus's would be optimal form triangles. For lines, all of them are mostly trivial but I think sum of angles is an intersting proof.

Comment: The Desargues's theorem is a consequence of Pappus's theorem, right?

Comment: I saw now that as regards thr triangles there are also the menelaos and ceva theorems, and some otherrelated to that. For these we should just mention them and show some pictures and not try to prove them, or what do you mean?

Comment: I would show maybe 4 or 5 theorems, deeply prove 1 or 2, and for the others give an example, explain how it relates, etc but don't go into too much detail. Just my thoughts.

Comment: Or should we mention only the theorem of menelaos and ceva and their consequences and not the theorem about angles, which are easier? What do you think is the best to do?

Comment: Good idea. Honestly the angle theorems are quite basic in my opinion.Menelaus and Ceva are much better :)

Comment: Ok! I thought to give for Menelaus the idea of the proof na djust to mention Ceva. For a presentation we shouldn't give the whole proof, should we? Just the idea of the proof, or what do you think?

Comment: Maybe focus on one, you don't need to give a complete proof but still try to go step by step on how to get the theorem. Then relate it to the other